# Custom Object list duplicate count by field

Tags: java

How to count the duplicates, if "NULL" is repeated for country then count by country wise how many time "NULL" is found.

```
Sample s1 = new Sample("NULL", "AT");
Sample s2 = new Sample("TimeOut", "AT");
Sample s3 = new Sample("NULL", "AT");
Sample s4 = new Sample("NULL", "AT");
Sample s5 = new Sample("TimeOut", "AT");
Sample s6 = new Sample("TimeOut", "UK");
Sample s7 = new Sample("NULL", "UK");

ArrayList<Sample> sample = new ArrayList<Sample>();
    sample.add(s1);
    sample.add(s2);
    sample.add(s3);
    sample.add(s4);
    sample.add(s5);
    sample.add(s6);
    sample.add(s7);
```

i want output :

"AT" : 3
"UK" : 1

Comment: Sample class properties (private String error;
 private String country;)

Comment: How should your input map to your expected output? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Put the Samples into a list and iterate over it.

Comment: could you please help me on this Jacob G.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class FilterAndGroup {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample s1 = new Sample("NULL", "AT");
        Sample s2 = new Sample("TimeOut", "AT");
        Sample s3 = new Sample("NULL", "AT");
        Sample s4 = new Sample("NULL", "AT");
        Sample s5 = new Sample("TimeOut", "AT");
        Sample s6 = new Sample("TimeOut", "UK");
        Sample s7 = new Sample("NULL", "UK");

        List<Sample> sample = new ArrayList<Sample>();
        sample.add(s1);
        sample.add(s2);
        sample.add(s3);
        sample.add(s4);
        sample.add(s5);
        sample.add(s6);
        sample.add(s7);

        // Filter the samples by those having the value "NULL". Group the filtered
        // samples by country.
        Map<String, List<Sample>> countryToSamples = sample.stream().filter(s -> s.value.equals("NULL"))
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> ((Sample) s).country));

        // The result of the above operation is a map from country to list of "NULL"
        // samples for this country. We print a summary of this map.
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Sample>> entry : countryToSamples.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s: %d", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().size()));
        }
    }

    static class Sample {
        String value;
        String country;

        public Sample(String value, String country) {
            this.value = value;
            this.country = country;
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
AT: 3
UK: 1
```

Comment: thank you so much.can you please help me before java 7.
Thank you so much for your support

Comment: Java 7 is deprecated, use a current version.

Comment: actually my requirement is java 7 only, if i update 8 there might be production issue are came.its on java 7

Comment: Java 7 has been deprecated since 2015, there are security fixes that are in the later java version so highly recommend you push for the updated version

Comment: If you can't use a current Java version, you will have to loop over the samples. But the logic is the same: Loop, filter, collect.

Comment: could you please help me on this @ Lutz Horn thank you for your great support.

Comment: How about trying?

Answer (score 0):

This is the above class modified for Java 7. Note that `import java.util.stream.Collectors;` has been removed, this class does not exist in Java 7. 
I've checked the execution with `jdk 1.7.0_80`.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class FilterAndGroupForJava7 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sample sample1 = new Sample("NULL", "AT");
        Sample sample2 = new Sample("TimeOut", "AT");
        Sample sample3 = new Sample("NULL", "AT");
        Sample sample4 = new Sample("NULL", "AT");
        Sample sample5 = new Sample("TimeOut", "AT");
        Sample sample6 = new Sample("TimeOut", "UK");
        Sample sample7 = new Sample("NULL", "UK");

        List<Sample> samples = new ArrayList<>();
        samples.add(sample1);
        samples.add(sample2);
        samples.add(sample3);
        samples.add(sample4);
        samples.add(sample5);
        samples.add(sample6);
        samples.add(sample7);

        // Filter the samples by those having the value "NULL". Group the filtered
        // samples by country.
        Map<String, List<Sample>> countryToSamples = new HashMap<>();
        for (Sample sample : samples) {
            if (sample.value.equals("NULL")) {
                List<Sample> currentSamplesByCountry = countryToSamples.get(sample.country);
                if (currentSamplesByCountry == null) {
                    currentSamplesByCountry = new ArrayList<>();
                    countryToSamples.put(sample.country, currentSamplesByCountry);
                }

                currentSamplesByCountry.add(sample);
            }
        }

        // The result of the above operation is a map from country to list of "NULL"
        // samples for this country. We print a summary of this map.
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Sample>> entry : countryToSamples.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println(String.format("%s: %d", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().size()));
        }
    }

    static class Sample {
        String value;
        String country;

        public Sample(String value, String country) {
            this.value = value;
            this.country = country;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Oops, sorry, I haven't noticed that `computeIfAbsent` does not exists in Java 7's `Map`. I updated the answer with the whole class that works in Java 7.